# How to fix ifconfig eth0

Tags: networking, server, dhcp

I followed a step from this answer:

> 1 down vote Your problem is no default route is available as you see (route commanr response). This isobviously because of dhcp failed. So
>   now you can set your network manually or read dhclient man.
>
> Ok manually:
>
> Set your interface ip an mask
>
> `sudo ifconfig eth0 <ipinsideyournrtwork> 255.255.255.0` ip inside your
>   network can be 10.0.0.4 or 192.168.0.4 . Now you can set default route
>   toyour gateway (router)
>
> But you must get router ip first. Fortunately you set your interface
>   ip and this is where your network address comes from (ip masked by
>   netmask). To get your router ip requires change the address end .4 to
>   some common number like 1 or 138 or 254. The router ip and client ip
>   must belong to the same network to get ping functional. So try: ping
>   10.0.0.1 first when you set your ip 10.0.0.4, etc. If you can ping your router then set the default route:
>
> `sudo route default add gw <yourrouterip> eth0` Cool you can check your
>   default route with the route command. The last step is set your dns
>   server. But check your default route before, just try ping some ip
>   outside your network, like google dns server 8.8.8.8 .

over on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370371/sudo-dhclient-eth0-sudo-unable-to-resolve-host-ubuntu-maybe-dns-issue/370409#370409) question. This broke my connection to my server and I was wondering what I could do to fix/revert it. Thanks!

Output /etc/network/interfaces:

```
# interfaces (5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
Iface lo inet loopback
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Please elaborate.

Comment: @SurajThapar I'll edit it.

Comment: Do you have physical access to the server or were you using SSH?

Comment: @SurajThapar I do have physical access

Comment: Please post the contents of your server's `/etc/network/interfaces` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To configure your system to use a static IP address assignment, add the static method to the inet address family statement for the appropriate interface in the file `/etc/network/interfaces`. The example below assumes you are configuring your first Ethernet interface identified as eth0. Change the address, netmask, and gateway values to meet the requirements of your network.

Edit the file so it looks like this (making the appropriate changes to address, netmask, and gateway). Make sure that the static ip address is well outside your router's dhcp range.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.0.0.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.0.0.1
```

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html